# Which spaces are most naturally presented simplicially?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

It's often a great technical convenience to know that you can "do homotopy theory" with simplicial sets. But if you really get down to it geometrically, it can be awkward.

In general, if I have a CW complex that I want to study simplicially, I have to build up a simplicial structure cell-by-cell, and I need to keep applying barycentric subdivision to simplicially approximate my attaching maps.

There are a few interesting spaces with economical simplicial structures. For example spheres, or $K(G,1)$'s (for which one can take the nerve of $G$ as a model), and suspensions thereof. I suppose Moore spaces aren't too bad either. One trick suggested by this is to take classifying spaces of other categories, but when it comes down to it there really aren't that many categories whose classifying spaces I know.

As far as I can tell, that might be about it! For example, even to write down a simplicial structure on $\mathbb C \mathbb P^\infty$ that I could actually work with, I'm not sure what I'd do. I could imagine that if there were an "economical" model of $S^1$ which was a simplicial topological group, then one could perform a bar construction to get $\mathbb C \mathbb P^\infty$, but I don't even really know a good model for $S^1$ as a simplicial group, short of geometrically realizing and taking the singular complex, which I think is very far from economical. It's not even clear to me whether $Ex^\infty S^1$ is a simplicial topological group!

**Questions:**

1. Is there a general method to write down a simplicial model of a homotopy type which is more economical than just subdividing to simplicially aproximate each attaching map?
2. Are there at least some examples of homotopy types which are not suspensions of $K(G,1)$'s or Moore spaces which admit "simple" simplicial models? By "simple", I roughly mean that one might really think about the space "geometrically", rather than just on some formal level.
3. As a test case, what would be a good simplicial model for $\mathbb C \mathbb P^\infty$?

**EDIT:** I should clarify that when I talk about a "simplicial model" of a homotopy type, I'm asking for a simplical set whose geometric realization has that homotopy type. I'm not requiring a simplicial complex or anything.

Comment: Concerning the comment about CP^∞: why not just take Γ(Z[2]), where Γ:Ch→sAb is the Dold–Kan functor?

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Actually, that sounds like a great idea! I'll have to ponder what comes out, but it seems about as economical as one could like!

Comment: There are some reasons to expect that there might be an efficient and explicit algebraic/combinatorial simplicial model for the space $\Omega^\infty K(n)$, but I do not believe that anyone has ever produced one.  This is potentially a rather interesting problem.

Comment: @NeilStrickland That sounds very interesting; could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @Tim, I don't know if the resulting simplicial model is "economical", but (and you probably already know this) one can often construct models for "moduli-theoretic" spaces (like the union ∐_n BU(n) and the zeroth space of Thom spectra) as geometric realizations of Kan complexes/quasicategories (groupoids of vector spaces and cobordism categories, in the above examples) given by the simplicial nerve of a topologically enriched category whose objects are the structures parametrized by the space, and whose morphisms impose the equivalence relation implicit in the moduli-theoretic problem.

Comment: @skd I suppose the part that gets me is that you need to use a topologically enriched category. In order to "simplicialize" this, you need to take the singular complex of the topological direction, unless you've already got a simplicial structure on the topolgical part. And singular complexes are extravagantly large. So for instance I'm not sure how to get from this a simplicial model for $BU$, say, which doesn't have uncountably many cells. Hmm, I wonder if Snaith's theorem could help with this... And similarly Westerland's theorem for $K(n)$...

Comment: @skd The Postnikov tower for $\Omega^\infty K(n)$ is very thin and quite regular.  The corresponding minimal Kan complex is a twisted form of $\prod_kK(\mathbb{Z}/p,2(p^n-1)k)$, and the first nontrivial $k$-invariant is the Milnor Bockstein operation $Q_n$.  It seems plausible that there should be an explicit simplicial map realising $Q_n$, which might be describable in terms of the McClure-Smith operad.  One might hope that this would involve congruences of binomial coefficients and so make contact with formal group theory.

Comment: If we interpret your question a little more broadly, it's well known that delta complexes give efficient (and very useful) descriptions for surfaces and "most" cusped hyperbolic 3-manifolds.   There's some beautiful delta complex structures on $\mathbb CP^2$ and I imagine many of them fit into a natural family.  Ben Burton and I found a delta complex structure on $\mathbb CP^2$ with just four $4$-dimensional simplices.

Comment: @RyanBudney I've always been a little confused about the definition of a Delta-complex, but looking back, it seems to me that a Delta-complex is exactly the same thing as the geometric realization of a simplicial set! In any event, this is really cool, thanks!

Comment: A delta complex is the geometric realization of a semi-simplicial set, not a simplicial set.  If you want to make a simplicial set whose realization is the 2-sphere, you can do it with just one 0-simplex and one non-degenerate 2-simplex (i.e., identifying the whole boundary of the 2-simplex to the point).  This isn't allowed in delta-complex land, where the cheapest way to make a 2-sphere is probably to identify the boundaries of two 2-simplices, making a 2-sphere with 3 0-cells, 3 1-cells and two 2-cells.

Comment: @IJL Ah, thanks! I suppose this is fine, since the realization of a semisimplicial set is the same as the realization of the free simplicial set on it.